# show that $\frac {1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2} e^{-itx}dx=e^{-t^2/2}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration

By integrating $e^{{-z^2}/2}$ around a rectangle with vertices $\pm R; it\pm R$;and sending $R$ to $\infty$, show that
$\frac {1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2} e^{-itx}dx=e^{-t^2/2}$
￼￼Use the known value of the integral for $t = 0$.

Now $\int _{\partial D} e^{{-z^2}/2}dz= \int _{-R}^R e^{{-x^2}/2}dx+ \int _0^te^{{-(R+iy)^2}/2}idy + \int _{R}^{-R} e^{{-x^2}/2}dx+  \int _t^0e^{{-(-R+iy)^2}/2}idy=0$.

Now what shall I do? Do I have to integrate this all?

Comment: The scale factor should be $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$.  And two of the four integrals go to zero as $R\to \infty$.

Comment: See also proof 10 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have from the [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem#Statement_of_theorem)

$$\begin{align}
\oint_Ce^{-z^2/2}\,dz&=0\\\\
&=\int_{-R}^Re^{-x^2/2}\,dx+\int_0^t e^{-(R+iy)^2/2}\,i\,dy\\\\
&+\int_{R}^{-R}e^{-(x+it)^2/2}\,dx+\int_t^0e^{-(-R+iy)^2/2}\,i\,dy \tag 1
\end{align}$$

It is easy to see that for any fixed $t>0$, the integrals in $(1)$ over $y$ approach $0$ as $R\to \infty$ since $e^{-R^2/2}\to 0$ as $R\to \infty$.  Therefore, we have

$$\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{-R}^Re^{-x^2/2}\,dx=\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{-R}^{R}e^{-(x+it)^2/2}\,dx \tag 2$$

Now, upon expanding the terms in the exponent on the right-hand side of $(2)$ and simplifying we obtain

$$\sqrt{2\pi}=e^{t^2/2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2/2}e^{-itx}\,dx$$

Finally, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2/2}e^{-itx}\,dx=e^{-t^2/2}}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Sure.  First, thank you for your alerting me to the inadvertent ommission of the term $i$ in the integral over $y$ .  I've edited accordingly.  Second, to arrive at $1$, we simply parameterie piecewise the rectangular contour with vertices at $R$, $R+it$, $-R+it$, and $-R$.

Comment: They are $z=x$ for $-R\le x\le R$,  $z=R+iy$ for $0\le y\le t$, $z=x+it$ for $-R\le x\le R$, and $z=-R+iy$ for $0\le y\le t$.

Comment: May I ask you how did you get your first step? I really don't see how did you decompose the boundary of the rectangle into 4 small piece

Comment: @BudLightD.Va I'm not sure as to the meaning of your question.  As explicitly written, the "first step" is simply a consequence of Cauchy's Integral Theorem.  The integrand is an entire function and hence the value of its integral around any rectifiable closed contour is $0$.

Comment: what i want to ask is why \[ oint_C = \int_{-R}^{R} dx + \int_^{t} idy + \int_R^{-r} dx + \int_t^0 idy \], I know you can write $dz = dx + idy$, but can you explain further about how did you get (1) please?

Comment: @BudLightD.Va Well, how do you write the contour integral around the rectangle with vertices at $(R,0)$, and $(R,t)$, and $(-R,t)$, and $(-R,0)$<

Comment: Thank you Mark, I just realized i misread the problem, thanks for your comment.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Btw, in the last integral, the integrand should be $ e^{-x^2/2}e^{-itx}$, i think you missed a minus sign

Comment: Good catch!  I've edited accordingly.  Thank you.